# store characters from array of pointers to normal array

Tags: c, arrays, string, ncurses

I would like to display the words inside buffer, except for the first word.
Elements of `buffer` point to the following strings:

```
 buffer[0] = "print"
 buffer[1] = "hello"
 buffer[2] = "my"
 …
```

Code:

```
char **buffer = getArray(); /* works OK */

char **print_array=buffer;
strcpy((char *)print_array[0],"");
mvwprintw(output, cursor, 2, "%s", print_array);
```

The above code prints a couple of characters which make no sense. I would like the above to display "hello my name" .

Comment: Huh?  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: I don't know any kind of *ab*normal array.  Every array is a contiguous sequence of elements of the same type.  In particular, pointer types are just as good as any other for array element types.

Comment: `strcpy((char *)print_array[0],"");` the cast to `char*` is completely superfluos.

Comment: Since `print_array` is a `char **`, it is not a suitable argument to `mvwprintw()` to correspond with a `%s` directive.  The argument corresponding to such directives must be of type `char *`.  E.g. `print_array[0]`.

Comment: how can I store the buffer contents into array print_array, if print_array where to be declared as char print_array[200];

Comment: You need a for loop and function `strcat()`.